# How to set right view width to wrapcontent and left view width to remaining space

Tags: android

Hello I've a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation where I have two Buttons. I want to set the right button width to wrap_content and left button width to remaining width.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way to do using weight_sum and weight property of it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first change android:orientation="vertical"  to android:orientation="horizontal". and yes you use android:weightSum="1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do using weight_sum and weight property of it ?

The answer is:`weight` property - yes, `weight_sum` property - no.

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But you need to specify the `width` of the whole layout (either as a precise value or as `match_parent`; width because you wrote that its supposed to be horizontal layout)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use both just try:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use weight to set the width proportionally. If you know how much space the left button takes in relation to the other you can use weight.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help you :)